# Echo values back into the drop-down to be edited and saved

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 drop-down boxes, which work great.  I'm able to choose the values from 3 different tables and submit/save to a summary table via the various table ID's.  However, I'd also like to be able to edit these values in the same drop down fields.  I have an edit function that sends the summary table ID to a $_GET function to identify the row. The values currently show up in 3 text boxes, but I'd rather they populate into the same drop-down fields instead. I'm unable to get the options syntax correct.. I'm thinking I need a "selected" option in there somewhere. I only want the proj_hours column to be updated, but still want all 3 drop-down's populated with values.

I hope that makes sense?  I want to get rid of the text boxes.

Most recent code:

```
<?php

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    //grabs ID from the initial edit submit 
//grabs ID from the initial edit submit 
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
echo "<pre>Value of \$_GET:</br>";print_r($_GET);echo"</pre>";  
    {
        $summary_id = $_GET['summary_id'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT *
                    FROM summary S
                    JOIN projects P ON S.proj_id = P.proj_id
                    JOIN departments D ON D.dept_id = S.dept_id
                    JOIN hours H ON H.hours_id = S.hours_id
                    WHERE S.summary_id = '$_GET[id]'
                    ORDER BY D.dept_id
                    LIMIT 0 , 30");

        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);

//echo "<pre>Value of \$rows:</br>";print_r($rows);echo"</pre>";  //was using to check what's going on 
        }

//submits the edited values, does a join to find out what's what, and inserts the correct digits into the summary DB        
    if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))  
echo "<pre>Value of \$_POST:</br>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>";
    {
//echo "<pre>Value of \$_POST:</br>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>";
        $summary_id     = $_POST['summary_id'];     
        $nclarity_id    = $_POST['nclarity_id'];
        $nproj_hours    = $_POST['nproj_hours'];
        $ndept_name     = $_POST['ndept_name'];

        $sql1           = "UPDATE summary S
                            SET S.hours_id = (
                            SELECT H.hours_id  
                            FROM Hours H 
                            WHERE H.proj_hours = '$nproj_hours' )
                            WHERE S.summary_id = '$summary_id'" 
                            or die ("couldn't update".mysql_error());

//multiple queries to get the field edited - i know this can be done more efficiently and safely, but I'm not proficient enough                         
        $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
        if ($query1)
{
echo "success_1!";
}
else
            {
        die('error inserting new record_1'.mysql_error());
    } // end of the nested if statement

}

 if (isset($_POST['btnnew']))  

    {
    //echo "<pre>Value of \$_POST:</br>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>";

        $nclarity_id    = $_POST['nclarity_id'];
        $nproj_hours    = $_POST['nproj_hours'];
        $ndept_name     = $_POST['ndept_name'];
        $proj_id        = $_POST['nclarity_id'];
        $hours_id       = $_POST['nproj_hours'];
        $dept_id        = $_POST['ndept_name'];

        $sql        = "INSERT INTO `summary` VALUES (null,'$proj_id','$hours_id','$dept_id',NOW(),null)" 
                            or die ("couldn't update".mysql_error());
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($query)
{
echo "success_2!";
}
else
            {
        die('error inserting new record_2'.mysql_error());
    } // end of the nested if statement
}

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT *
                    FROM summary S
                    JOIN projects P ON S.proj_id = P.proj_id
                    JOIN departments D ON D.dept_id = S.dept_id
                    JOIN hours H ON H.hours_id = S.hours_id
                    WHERE P.proj_status = 'open'
                    ORDER BY D.dept_id
                                        LIMIT 0 , 30"); 

?>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <td>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center"><strong>Clarity ID</strong></td>
   <td align="center"><strong>Hours</strong></td>
   <td align="center"><strong>Department</strong></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </td>
   </form>
   </tr>
   </table>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>

<select name="nclarity_id">
<option name="">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT proj_id, clarity_id FROM projects WHERE proj_status='open'";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

$id = -9999; // a value that cannot exist in your database
if(isset($_GET['proj_id'])) { // check if there is an id in the $_GET variable
    $id = $_GET['proj_id']; // if so, set the $id variable
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $selectedText = "";
    if($row['proj_id'] == $id) { // if this row id is the same as the post id
        $selectedText = ' selected="selected"'; // set some text to be included in the markup
    }
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['proj_id']."\"".$selectedText.">".$row['clarity_id']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="nproj_hours">
<option name="">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT hours_id, proj_hours FROM hours";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$id = -9999; // a value that cannot exist in your database
if(isset($_GET['hours_id'])) { // check if there is an id in the $_GET variable
    $id = $_GET['hours_id']; // if so, set the $id variable
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $selectedText = "";
    if($row['hours_id'] == $id) { // if this row id is the same as the post id
        $selectedText = ' selected="selected"'; // set some text to be included in the markup
    }
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['hours_id']."\"".$selectedText.">".$row['proj_hours']."</option>\n  ";

}
?>
</select>
<select name="ndept_name">
<option name="">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT dept_id, dept_name FROM departments";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$id = -9999; // a value that cannot exist in your database
if(isset($_GET['dept_id'])) { // check if there is an id in the $_GET variable
    $id = $_GET['dept_id']; // if so, set the $id variable
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $selectedText = "";
    if($row['hours_id'] == $id) { // if this row id is the same as the post id
        $selectedText = ' selected="selected"'; // set some text to be included in the markup
    }
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['dept_id']."\"".$selectedText.">".$row['dept_name']."</option>\n  ";

}
?>
</select>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="btnnew" value="Enter New Record">
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Save Edited Record">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><strong>Project Information </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Clarity ID</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Estimated Hours</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Department</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong></strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

?>

<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['clarity_id']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['proj_hours']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['dept_name']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['date_entered']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $row['summary_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}

?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the same options list, but check to see if the id is the same as the id you find in the $_POST or $_GET array.

EDIT: just realised that you speicifed $_GET - substitute $_POST with $_GET in the example below.

Something like:

```
$id = -9999; // a value that cannot exist in your database
if(isset($_POST['proj_id'])) { // check if there is an id in the $_POST variable
    $id = $_POST['proj_id']; // if so, set the $id variable
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $selectedText = "";
    if($row['proj_id'] == $id) { // if this row id is the same as the post id
        $selectedText = ' selected="selected"'; // set some text to be included in the markup
    }
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['proj_id']."\"".$selectedText.">".$row['clarity_id']."</option>\n  ";

}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT to answer comment:

Hi Mike, I've checked your code again, there's a bit of confusion with the `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables. You find the `$_POST` variables from your form when it is submitted. The `$_GET` variables are from the URL. When you click the "edit" link, you are redirecting to index.php, and you are passing a single variable, called "id". At this point, your `$_GET` array will contain a single key/value pair, called "id" and its value. Yet, I notice in your code you are trying to get a variable called 'summary_id' from the `$_GET` array, which probably doesn't exist. Also, before you construct each options list, you are looking for `$_GET['proj_id']`, `$_GET['hours_id']` and `$_GET['dept_id']`, which again don't exist. In summary, on the "edit" page, you are searching for variables which you haven't passed in the URL. This is probably why your dropdown lists are not being populated. One solution would be to change your "edit" link so that you pass also the `proj_id`, `dept_id` and `hours_id` variables. Also, bear in mind that the $_POST array is only populated when the form is submitted, and is only available to the page specified in the "action" attribute of the form element. As soon as you navigate away from that page (even if you navigate to the same page, as you are doing with your "edit" link), the $_POST array is no longer populated.

Comment: I'm getting a parse error now.  I added my edited section with your code - can you see any issues with it?  I did find a missing ";", but can't see anything else.

Comment: You're missing the last "}", I think :) - By the way... why did you set the `$selectedText` to `"Project"`? That will create markup that looks like `<option value="row_id"Project>description</option>`

Comment: oh yep, good catch... I know enough to be dangerous..lol  Let me go test that out and I'll let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Fixed one only to get another. :)  I get the parse error when I hit my edit function:   <td align="center"><a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $row['summary_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>

Comment: Ok, no errors (I fixed it), but now there's no values that populate the dropdowns when I click my edit function.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted above - are you getting any response from the database? I didn't explicitly write the query - you either need to write the query and interrogate the database again, or (better), remember the output from the first time you ran the query.

Comment: yeah I'm digging through it now.  I need to leave for a bit, but will finish it up shortly and let you know.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I see the issue, but not sure how to fix.  It's passing the summary_id after I click edit as it should be.  The $_GET function is grabbing it as it should, but that's where it dies. The drop downs are looking for the edited variables (prefaced with an "n") but it's passing the normal variables.  I have a love/hate relationship with coding...lol  Soooo close.  Oh, and I posted the updated code if that helps.

Comment: Ok I think I understand that, but why would it pass the variables to my text boxes on "edit", but not with the dropdowns?  That is the piece I'm struggling with. It works fine if I click edit, it sends the id over, grabs the table values, and posts them in the text boxes... but how many people want to type the values in manually and also have to be 100% in the spelling to be able to submit.. hehe  I'll keep working on it.  Is the problem because I'm using an html submit function/form as opposed to the dropdowns?  that might be my hang-up. Thanks again for hanging in there! :)

Comment: Got it working the ghetto unsecured way, but that'll work for now as it's only being used as an example for an internal blah blah blah....lol  and for me to learn.  THANK YOU!!  I ended up passing the variables through the edit function, using "&".  id=id2&id2=id3, etc etc